# AWS Lake formation Granting Permission to Linked Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-lake-formation

I am attempting to grant permission on a linked resource to a role within the same account as my Data Lake Admin role. But, I'm not seeing any changes after I Grant.

Here are details on the setup:

- There's a **producer** account and **consumer** account. I am the **consumer** account
- Producer has shared database with **consumer** account
- In **consumer** account:

  - Add "admin-role" as Data Lake Administrator
  - In Lake Formation console: Databases > Create Database > select "Resource Link" > Resource link name: database_link > Shared Database: *type in databasename from producer account* (producer database did not populate in the list) > Shared database's owner ID: *key in **producer** account id*
  - Grant permission to another role in the same account as the consumer, but this role IS NOT a member of Data Lake Administrator. This role is a business user role, let's call it "business-role"

    - In Lake Formation Console: Data lake permissions > Grant > IAM users and roles > select the "business-role" > Named data catalog resources > Database: *in drop down, select the resource link database* > Tables: All tables > Table permissions: Select, Describe > Grant

At this point, when I search for the "business-role" in Data lake permissions pane, I would expect a row that confirms access has been granted for that role to all tables like the following:
[image]

But, I have tried over and over again, for some reason the grant is not sticking. Although, I am seeing confirmation that permission has been added.

I have also tried using CLI command:

- This is the command: `aws lakeformation grant-permissions --cli-input-json file://lf_permissions.json`
- This is the content of the json:

```
`{
    "CatalogId": "consumer-account-id",
    "Principal": {
        "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": "arn:aws:iam::consumer-account-id:role/business-role"
    },
    "Resource": {
        "Table": {
            "CatalogId": "consumer-account-id",
            "DatabaseName": "database_link",
            "TableWildcard": {}
        }
    },
    "Permissions": [
        "SELECT"
    ],
    "PermissionsWithGrantOption": []
}`
```

This executed without any error. But, still when I list-permissions or view in the console, I don't see anything.

I'm hoping someone has any other ideas I can try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help here. I may have missed it but what are the privileges granted to the Admin user on the consumer account? For one thing, I have found there is an issue with Lake Formation console, many times I am missing permissions and have to query each table separately to find the permissions I recently granted. You can query for them by using boto3 in python or whatever coding language sdk you like. Something like this:

```
resp = lf.list_permissions(
            Principal={
                'DataLakePrincipalIdentifier': rolearn
            },
            Resource={
                'Table': {
                    'DatabaseName': database,
                    'Name': table
                }
            }
        )['PrincipalResourcePermissions']
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I thought I was going crazy with the way things were not showing up in the console. We wrote a python script using boto3 to return a list of permissions and this helped us debug so much easier. 

We did finally get the permissions working. I wish I had an answer of how we got it to work though. We pretty much threw everything that we can think of at the permissions (probably even attempting to apply the same permissions several times). After a week of this, it finally worked.